# bootstrap select not working in jquery pep

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap select and the plugin [jquery.pep.js](https://github.com/briangonzalez/jquery.pep.js/)
the problem is, the select option will not open or I cannot choose options.

here is the code

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="pep peppable">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <select class="form-control">
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
          <option>5</option>
        </select>
      </div>


    </form>

  </div>

</div>
```

js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.peppable').pep({  constrainTo: 'parent' });

      });
```

see [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/h356v0xu/2/)

Comment: Both jquery are clashing.

Comment: check here https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/h356v0xu/3/

Comment: @Leothelion , if I will remove the jquery js but how I can use jquery and jquery.pep.js ? because in my site I need also to use jquery.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Read this usage](https://github.com/briangonzalez/jquery.pep.js/#usage) `shouldPreventDefault`

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SeokjunHong/h356v0xu/4/)